# Build starts on Unit Test Execution

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am using VS2013 Ultimate with the Update 2 RC.

My problem is the following: Whenever I am starting an Unit Test all dependent projects for the Unit Test are built. Even if the dependencies did not change. This costs a lot of time during development and I do not know how to deactivate it.

I am using Visual Studio Unit Tests. If found a suggestion to set
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> On Run, .. -> to Never Build.
However this does not work for me.

I also found a similar problem to mine and Microsoft stated it as fixed. For me not the whole solutions gets rebuilt but every dependency. So it is different. However here is the link:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809777/running-a-single-unit-test-in-visual-studio-2013-causes-entire-solution-to-be-built

Maybe I am missing out an option. Maybe it has to be rebuilt because of something I am missing out. Another Option would be that VS2013 is still buggy. But then I think somebody else would have encountered the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the final Update 2? Can you reproduce on a  new solution with just `ClassLibrary1` and `UnitTestProject1` and all the default settings?

Comment: I updated, now it works. I still don't get why they would mark the issue as fixed if it is not.
I know they mark it as fixed for "this or the next version". But they did not fix it in the release candidate and that was the next version. Maybe the only count the final versions, this did not occur to me.
Anyway... If you make an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment -- upgrading to the final Update 2 seems to solve the issue.